# xterm window cannot be held on Linux, it appears and then disappears very fast

Tags: c++, linux, gdb, mpi, xterm

I am doing degug for MPI C++ on Linux with GDB.

I cannot use the following command:

```
xterm -e gdb mpirun -np 1 ./myApplication
```

to open a window for the executable program `./myApplication`: the xterm terminal appears and then disappears immediately.

Why does this happen?

I can open an xterm with:

```
xterm or xterm -e gdb.
```

Any help is really appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

@chatan almost got it right.

If you want to invoke `gdb` on a program while passing arguments to that program, you need to use gdb's `--args` option.  For example (I don't have `mpirun`, so I'll use `/bin/sleep`):

```
$ gdb --args /bin/echo hello
[...]
Reading symbols from /bin/echo...(no debugging symbols found)...done.
(gdb) run
Starting program: /bin/echo hello
hello

Program exited normally.
```

`gdb` doesn't automatically start running the program; it waits for input.

Without the `--args` option, `gdb` takes `-np` as a `gdb` option, not as an argument to `mpirun`.  Since `gdb` doesn't have a `-np` option, it terminates with an error message:

```
$ gdb mpirun -np 1 ./myApplication
gdb: unrecognized option '-np'
Use `gdb --help' for a complete list of options.
```

And when you run `xterm -e gdb mpirun -np 1 ./myApplication`, `xterm` runs, it invokes `gdb`, `gdb` terminates with an error message, and `xterm` terminates before you get a chance to see the message.

So this should do the trick:

```
xterm -e gdb --args mpirun -np 1 ./myApplication
```

Of course you'll still have to type the `run` command within `gdb` to invoke `mpirun`.  (If you're using gdb, you probably already know that.)

For future reference, if you have problems running a program under `xterm -e`, try running it by itself.

Answer (score 1):

Your command is not going to work the way you expect it to anyway. gdb will ignore the arguments after 'mpirun'. And a naked mpirun command, without any arguments, is going to immediately exit (just try running mpirun by hand in a terminal). Since your xterm was started to execute that one command, it disappears after that process is finished.

What you need to do is, open an xterm. Then run "gdb mpirun" command.

You should end up in gdb command prompt. At this prompt, you need to issue the following command:

(gdb) run -np 1 ./myApplication

Now your application should be running inside gdb.